# Using time filter in dashboard to change range of Vega in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I am using Kibana 7.1.

I have successfully created Vega line plot. I can allow it to show month of data however I want user to play around with time filter in dashboard and allow vega visualization to change with it.

From https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-vega-visualizations-in-kibana and in Vega documentation I've read that inserting

```
  "%context%": true,
  "%timefield%": "@timestamp"
```

inside url will resolve this issue however when I do this it gives me 
`url.%context% and url.%timefield% must not be used when url.body.query is set`

my full elasticsearch code look like this:

```
  "data": {
    "url": {
      "%context%":"true",
      "index": "access_log",
      "body": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {"term": {"request_1": "rent"}},
              {"term": {"status": 200}}
            ]
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "histo": {
            "date_histogram": {
              "field": "date",
              "interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "start_agg": {
                "filter": {
                  "term": {"request_2": "start"}
                }
              },
              "check_agg": {
                "filter": {
                  "term": {"request_2": "check"}
                }
              },
              "start_check": {
                "bucket_script": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                    "start_count": "start_agg._count",
                    "check_count": "check_agg._count"
                  },
                  "script": "params.start_count / params.check_count"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "format": {
      "property": "aggregations.histo.buckets"
    }
  },
  "mark": {
    "type":"line"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "key",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"title": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "start_check.value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "Document count"}
    },
    "tooltip":[
      {"field":"start_check.value", 
       "type" : "quantitative"},
      {"field":"key",
       "type" :"temporal"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [Elastic's Vega reference for Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/vega-reference.html#vega-queries):

> When using `"%context%": true` or defining a value for `"%timefield%"` the body cannot contain a query. To customize the query within the VEGA specification (e.g. add an additional filter, or shift the timefilter), define your query and use the placeholders as in the example above. The placeholders will be replaced by the actual context of the dashboard or visualization once parsed.

The "example above" they are talking about is the following:

```
{
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          // This string will be replaced
          // with the auto-generated "MUST" clause
          "%dashboard_context-must_clause%"
          {
            range: {
              // apply timefilter (upper right corner)
              // to the @timestamp variable
              @timestamp: {
                // "%timefilter%" will be replaced with
                // the current values of the time filter
                // (from the upper right corner)
                "%timefilter%": true
                // Only work with %timefilter%
                // Shift current timefilter by 10 units back
                shift: 10
                // week, day (default), hour, minute, second
                unit: minute
              }
            }
          }
        ]
        must_not: [
          // This string will be replaced with
          // the auto-generated "MUST-NOT" clause
          "%dashboard_context-must_not_clause%"
        ]
        filter: [
          // This string will be replaced
          // with the auto-generated "FILTER" clause
          "%dashboard_context-filter_clause%"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And, just as already defined in the docs:

> - `"%dashboard_context-must_clause%"`: String replaced by object containing filters
> - `"%dashboard_context-filter_clause%"`: String replaced by an object containing filters
> - `"%dashboard_context-must_not_clause%"`: String replaced by an object containing filters

So, in case you want to use user-defined filters or the time filter having a customized query at the same time, you must use these three strings instead of `"%context%": true`. They will be parsed by Kibana and substituted by Elasticsearch query objects: one for "MUST", one for "FILTER" and one for "MUST_NOT", respectively.

A simple schema like this one might be useful:

```
{
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          // {
          //   A "MUST" clause of yours
          // },
          "%dashboard_context-must_clause%"
        ]
        must_not: [
          // {
          //   A "MUST_NOT" clause of yours
          // },
          "%dashboard_context-must_not_clause%"
        ]
        filter: [
          // {
          //   A "FILTER" clause of yours
          // },
          "%dashboard_context-filter_clause%"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In case you don't have any clause in some of the categories, just leave the corresponding `"%dashboard_context-XXXXX_clause%"` string without further objects - just like in the first example for "FILTER" or "MUST_NOT".

Answer (score 0):

inserting `"%timefield%":"date"` where date is one of my field worked.

Comment: You have a typo in that string. Are you sure it solves your issue? It seems to be giving error whenever timefield is set.